# color difference in safari, chrome, Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, background-color, color-profile

Can anyone explain, why am I seeing colour difference for hexcode **#49287c** (or rgb(73,40,124)) in Chrome, Firefox and Safari?

Does it have to do anything with colour profiles, as described [here](https://css-tricks.com/color-rendering-difference-firefox-vs-safari/)?

PS - Below screenshots produced on macOS using Chrome, Firefox, Safari with help of https://www.webpagefx.com/web-design/hex-to-rgb/

[image: Screenshot of colour difference]

Answer (score 0):

This is a color profile issue.  The behavior you are seeing is consistent with firefox not assuming hex colors are sRGB, which is the behavior of Safari.

Firefox has a preference, `gfx.color_management.mode` that determines how it handles colors. It can have the following values:

1: Color management disabled. (Default in Firefox 3.)
2: Full color management
3: Color management applied only to tagged images.  (Default in Firefox 3.5.)

Settings 1 and 3 won't treat hex colors like sRGB which is how Safari treats them. It will instead just send them to the video card and the colors will be shown in the monitor space.

You can change the behavior of Firefox by going to the url: about:config, finding the `gfx.color_management.mode` setting and changing it to `1`.

This should make the colors match much better.